# Basics of unbounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{\hat{O}}_{1}(x)$ and $\mathcal{\hat{O}}_{2}(x)$ be two one-parameter dependent operators which are possibly unbounded. Under what condition am I allowed use the replacement:

$$\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}}dx\,\mathcal{\hat{O}}_{1}(x)\,+\,\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}}dx\,\mathcal{\hat{O}}_{2}(x)\,=\,\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}}dx\,\left(\mathcal{\hat{O}}_{1}(x)+\mathcal{\hat{O}}_{2}(x)\right)$$

will this condition be sufficient to imply that
$$\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}}dt\:\mathcal{\hat{O}}(x)\,+\,\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}dt\:\mathcal{\hat{O}}(x)\,=\,\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{2}}dx\:\mathcal{\hat{O}}(x)\,?$$

Comment: This is not clear, an operator on what space? And if $A$ is an operator, what do you mean by $A(x)$?

Comment: @LL3.14: let us assume that the space is generally unknown, but should be dictated as a part of the answer. Is it correct that this property will hold only in linear spaces? Also, $x$ is just a parameter. For example, in physics questions this can be taken as the time variable. So the operator is generally not a constant.

Comment: @LL3.14: is there any way to share with you a document in which the details of this question are much better explained?